# ProgrammingError pymysql.err.1064 when Update in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I got an Error and I don't figure out why.
I have a store and for clients work perfect, but for products doesn't work (only) the update, it gives me this programming error. In MySQL the code run, but in Python it doesn't want.
Help

```
    with self.__engine.connect() as conn:
        query = conn.execute(text(f'SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = {product_id}'))
        values = query.first()
        if values:
            _, current_product_name, current_producer, current_category, current_price, current_stock = values
            conn.execute(text(f'UPDATE products '
                              f'SET product_name = "{product_name or current_product_name}", '
                              f'producer = "{producer or current_producer}", '
                              f'category = "{category or current_category}", '
                              f'price = "{price or current_price}", '
                              f'stock = "{stock or current_stock}", '
                              f'WHERE product_id = "{product_id}"'))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJOKC.png)

Comment: There is an extra comma before the where clause - it would not run directly in mysql either.

Comment: Thank you! :) stupid mistake. :))